# Run a function only once during runtime in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a requirement to load some data into memory. To do this, I need to ensure that my function that does this is run only once at runtime no matter how many times it is called.

I'm using a decorator to do this in a thread-safe manner.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
import threading

# Instantiating a lock object
# This will be used to ensure that multiple parallel threads will not be able to run the same function at the same time
# in the @run_once decorator written below
__lock = threading.Lock()


def run_once(f):
  """
  Decorator to run a function only once.

  :param f: function to be run only once during execution time despite the number of calls
  :return: The original function with the params passed to it if it hasn't already been run before
  """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        The actual wrapper where the business logic to call the original function resides

        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return: The original function unless the wrapper has been run already
        """
        if not wrapper.has_run:
          with __lock:
            if not wrapper.has_run:
              wrapper.has_run = True
              return f(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.has_run = False
    return wrapper
```

Do I need to do a double check on the `has_run` flag once outside and once inside the lock so that a read is not being done on a stale object ?

Comment: You can not drop the inner condition, since a thread could get past the outer condition while another is already inside the locked segment. You could drop the *outer* if condition, but that would cause every thread after the first to acquire a lock, only to then immediately return because the flag is set, which may be quite a bit of unnecessary overhead/waiting. I think checking the flag twice here is alright.

Comment: @Zinki My thoughts exactly. :)